# WebParts Removed From Web.config After WSP Deployment

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, solution-package, visual-studio-2015, safe-controls

I have a SharePoint 2013 web site with custom web parts.  Lately, I've been running into an issue in which all the safecontrol elements that correspond to my custom webparts disappear from SharePoint's `web.config` immediately after I deploy the site's WSP.  By safecontrol element, I refer to the following as an example:

```
 <SafeControl Assembly="MyApplication, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=69dcf65f3fee0271" Namespace="MyApplication.MyWebPart" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />;
```

I use the following Powershell command when updating the WSP:

```
Update-SPSolution –Identity [WSP file name] –LiteralPath [Physical path to WSP] –GACDeployment
```

The WSP is built using Visual Studio 2015.

Short-term solution is to copy the deleted safecontrol elements from a backup, but I don't want to keep having to do that.  I checked the `manifest.xml` in the WSP file.  All the safecontrols are there.  Any idea why the safecontrols would disappear after a WSP deployment?